# TSQL pattern matching with like

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to find columns that match the following condition.

- Must start with "Foo"
- Follow by a number of any length
- Follow by a space or "-"
- Follow by a number of any length
- End or follow by A,B,C, PE, a period, or a space

So the following would match

- Foo42004 45058
- Foo42004-45058
- Foo42004 45058A
- Foo42004 45058PE
- Foo42004 45058B.v34
- Foo42004-45058C bar
- Foo42004-45058C bar

The select statement would be something like the following, but I don't think it works

```
    select mycolumn 
    from mytable 
    where mycolumn like 'Foo[0-9]{0,15}[ -][0-9]{0,15}[A|B|C|PE]%'
```

Comment: [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc7c4/2/0), i've tried and... it does _not_ work. Read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Comment: [LIKE syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) is very limited. It's not regex.

Comment: Why would the last three lines match? Wouldn't they get excluded for not ending according to the last rule?

Comment: jpw, the last three would match.  If the string doesn't end it should be follow by A,B,C,PE, a period, or a space

Comment: @Duvo: You're right; think there's an additional rule (judging by the regex) that after the initial pattern anything's allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSQL has no notion of the {0,15} like in Regex.  So the part of your pattern Foo[0-9]{0,15} would match the strings Foo0{0,15}, Foo1{0,15}, Foo2{0,15}, ... Foo9{0,15} etc. Like BlorgBeard said, LIKE is limited.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to implement this would be to use a CLR to implement a real regular expression function. There are many free options available with a google search for "sql clr regex" as well as instructions on how to roll your own.

Your other option would be to build your own function, using T-SQL [string parsing functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx) to verify your format.

Answer (score 0):

A very hacky solution, making use of patindex's almost regex functionality:

```
select mycolumn 
from
(
    select mycolumn 
    , StartsFoo
    , case when patindex('%[^0-9]%',foo2)=0 and LEN(foo2) between 0 and 15 then 1 else 0 end HasZeroToFifteenDigits
    , SUBSTRING(foo3,patindex('%[^0-9]%',foo3 + 'x')+1,LEN(foo3)) foo4
    from
    (
        select mycolumn 
        , case when mycolumn  like 'Foo%' then 1 else 0 end StartsFoo
        , SUBSTRING(mycolumn ,4,case when patindex('%[- ]%',mycolumn )<4 then 0 else patindex('%[- ]%',mycolumn )-4 end) foo2
        , SUBSTRING(mycolumn ,case when patindex('%[- ]%',mycolumn )<0 then 0 else patindex('%[- ]%',mycolumn )+1 end,LEN(mycolumn )) foo3
        from mytable 
    ) x
) y
where StartsFoo * HasZeroToFifteenDigits * case when LEN(foo4)=0 or patindex('[A|B|C|PE|.| ]%',foo4)=1  then 1 else 0 end = 1
```

Demo Code:

```
declare @a table(foo nvarchar(32), shouldMatch bit)
insert @a
select 'Foo42004 45058', 1
union select 'Foo42004-45058', 1
union select 'Foo42004 45058A', 1
union select 'Foo42004 45058PE', 1
union select 'Foo42004 45058B.v34', 1
union select 'Foo42004-45058C bar', 1
union select 'Foo42004-45058C bar', 1
union select 'Goo42004-45058', 0
union select 'Foo42004x45058', 0
union select 'Foo42x04 45058', 0

select foo
, shouldMatch
, StartsFoo * HasZeroToFifteenDigits * case when LEN(foo4)=0 or patindex('[A|B|C|PE|.| ]%',foo4)=1  then 1 else 0 end doesMatch
from
(
    select foo
    , shouldMatch
    , StartsFoo
    , case when patindex('%[^0-9]%',foo2)=0 and LEN(foo2) between 0 and 15 then 1 else 0 end HasZeroToFifteenDigits
    , SUBSTRING(foo3,patindex('%[^0-9]%',foo3 + 'x')+1,LEN(foo3)) foo4
    from
    (
        select foo, shouldMatch
        , case when foo like 'Foo%' then 1 else 0 end StartsFoo
        , SUBSTRING(foo,4,case when patindex('%[- ]%',foo)<4 then 0 else patindex('%[- ]%',foo)-4 end) foo2
        , SUBSTRING(foo,case when patindex('%[- ]%',foo)<0 then 0 else patindex('%[- ]%',foo)+1 end,LEN(foo)) foo3
        from @a 
    ) x
) y
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22453